# Prevent hover property to apply when a fixed element is above

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of code:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div
        id="main-article-image"
        class="h-100 w-100 img-blur"
        style$="background-image: url('{{getArticleImage(article)}}');"
    >
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">Ariticle description...</div>   
</div>

<div id="article-container">...</div>
```

Here you are the CSS properties of those elementes:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: Raleway-Light;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 3;
}

.overlay:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.image-container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

#article-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: var(--my-elem-right);
    transition: right 0.3s linear;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I have my `#article-container` element set as `position: fixed` and when an element is clicked, it will be displayed above the `.image-container` element. The problem is that when the fixed element is displayed and I place the mouse hover where the `.overlay` element is placed (behind the fixed one) the `.overlay` text still displays and can be seen absolutely positioned on the page.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlHWA.jpg) you can see the usual behaviour of the element and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vALJb.jpg) the undesired one. The red mark shows where the mouse was placed in order to the `.overlay` element to be showed.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have defined a Z-index on the `.overlay` element and not on the other elements. You could fix it by having the following z-index hierarchy. Keep in mind that you always need a position value other than static for z-index to work.

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
#article-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I fixed it by just deleting the `z-index` property, it was just not necessary.